# Doctrine: DQL - GROUP_CONCAT for objects

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony2 webpage using Doctrine2 ORM.

I have a table of payments with column named `phone`. The problem is that I need to group all these payments by the phone number, but the result has to be an array of payments under the phone, not their count (result of simple GROUP BY).

Currently, I'm using a simple algorithm which parses a simple array of payments ([]) to associative array (phone => []). It works but I find it slightly ineffective for further development.

I was thinking of something like GROUP_CONCAT working on objects, not strings, but I haven't found any.

My DQL looks like this:

```
 SELECT p FROM payments as p WHERE = ...
```

And I'm looking for something like this:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p) FROM payments as p GROUP BY p.phone WHERE = ...
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
 array(5) {
      "123456789": [0 => Payment(), 1 => Payment()],
      "234567891": [0 => Payment()],
      ....
 }
```

The second query works well, because payment has defined a toString() method, however I need to manipulate with the object, so I'm not satisfied with string representation.

As I'm writing this post, I have to admit that the database is probably not designed properly. A M:N (like User (phone) : Payment) relationship might be actual solution, but I'm not sure if i would be allowed to make the design changes to our database.

How would you deal with it?

Comment: Actually, my current solution is slow as hell, so I really need your advice! Thanks